# Laravel's eloquent post-processing query

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, postgis

I am using PostgreSQL + PostGIS setup, and I want to fetch `geom` column from database as GeoJSON. I know I can do that using `ST_AsGeoJSON()` function. So i use this code to fetch all countries:

`$countries = Country::select(["id", "name", DB::raw("ST_AsGeoJSON(geom) AS geom")])->get()`

However, I end up with `$countries[i]->geom` being a string so I need to have for loop to do this:

`$countries[i]->geom = json_decode($countries[i]->geom);`

I would like to move this line of code to the Eloquent Model so I do not have to worry if I forget to decode column or not. Is there a method I should override or any way to add this special functionality to my Country model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to your model

```
protected $casts = [
    'geom' => 'array',
];
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

Comment: I am using 5.1 LTS version, but this works, also putting `'geom' => 'json'` does the trick.  But, I have checked laravel code, it actually do `json_decode()` each time I ask for this attribute... Answer from oseintow is good if I remember decoded value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use mutator/accessor to override or to decode the values in your model. So in your model do the following.

```
public function getGeomAttribute()
{
   return json_decode($this->attributes['geom']);
}
```

With this you can access geom at different part of your application without decoding it.

Comment: but isn't that inefficient on large scales, decoding it each time. I could make some private variable to check if it is already decoded and return that value...